# Duplicate URLs for same node

Tags: 7, nodes, uri

Yesterday I found that one article from my website is indexed more than once in Google, and I discovered that the URLs are like like the following ones.

- http://www.techiestuffs.com/gadgets/best-racing-games-available-android?page=1
- http://www.techiestuffs.com/gadgets/best-racing-games-available-android?page=2
- http://www.techiestuffs.com/gadgets/best-racing-games-available-android?page=3

The same node is generated many times.

The original link is http://www.techiestuffs.com/gadgets/best-racing-games-available-android.

This doesn't happen for just a node; all other nodes are also indexed more than once.

I am afraid Google will penalize us for this.

Do you know of any solution to avoid this?
For which reason does Google generate this type of URLs?

Answer (score 5):

You should be ok with regards to Google penalizing you because you've got a canonical link statement in each page which will tell Google that the page is really just a duplicate of the main page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/gadgets/best-racing-games-available-android">
```

[Google canonical link info](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Answer (score 2):

Those pages are generated from Views "paging" in this case (I assume) "the best racing games available on android" across 4 pages instead of putting them all on one, eg, the base url has the first X number of games, page=1 has the next X number of them, etc up to page 3.  Just as long as the content is different on each page, I don't *think* google will ding you.  But, if you are concerned, turn paging off in the view that generates this page and instead change it to show all items, and these extra pages will go away.